# Invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type question

Tags: c, sizeof

Im getting the error of

`invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'TProgmemRGBGradientPalette_byte* const [] {aka const unsigned char* const []}'`

On line 46 https://pastebin.com/xhVEnqts.

The last line below is line 46:

```
#define FASTLED_ALLOW_INTERRUPTS 0
#include "FastLED.h"
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFiMulti.h>
#include <WebSocketsClient.h> //  https://github.com/kakopappa/sinric/wiki/How-to-add-dependency-libraries
#include <ArduinoJson.h> // https://github.com/kakopappa/sinric/wiki/How-to-add-dependency-libraries
#include <StreamString.h>

#define DATA_PIN    3
#define LED_TYPE    WS2812
#define COLOR_ORDER GRB
#define NUM_LEDS    30       // Change this to reflect the number of LEDs you have
#define BRIGHTNESS  128       // Set Brightness here

CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

#define SECONDS_PER_PALETTE 15


ESP8266WiFiMulti WiFiMulti;
WebSocketsClient webSocket;
WiFiClient client;

#define MyApiKey "xxxx" // TODO: Change to your sinric API Key. Your API Key is displayed on sinric.com dashboard
#define MySSID "xxxxx" // TODO: Change to your Wifi network SSID
#define MyWifiPassword "xxxx" // TODO: Change to your Wifi network password

#define HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL 300000 // 5 Minutes

uint64_t heartbeatTimestamp = 0;
bool isConnected = false;

void setPowerStateOnServer(String deviceId, String value);
void setTargetTemperatureOnServer(String deviceId, String value, String scale);

extern const TProgmemRGBGradientPalettePtr gGradientPalettes[];
extern const uint8_t gGradientPaletteCount;

uint8_t gCurrentPaletteNumber = 0;

CRGBPalette16 gCurrentPalette( CRGB::Black);
CRGBPalette16 gTargetPalette( gGradientPalettes[0] );

const uint8_t gGradientPaletteCount =
sizeof( gGradientPalettes) / sizeof( TProgmemRGBGradientPalettePtr );
```

Comment: "Pastebin.com is under heavy load right now :(". Why don't you put the code in the question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, but more urgently, please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  You should be able to reduce your 46 lines to 2 of the lines shown plus a definition of some sort for the type `TProgmemRGBGradientPalettePtr`.  The full code — 600+ lines — certainly shouldn't be posted into the question, but an MCVE for this can be quote small.

Answer (score 1):

It extern variable with unknown compile time size. If you cant find the size looking at the code compiler will not as well

Answer (score 1):

An array type is an incomplete type if its size is not present, and `sizeof` cannot be applied on an incomplete type.

The following line means that the definition of `gGradientPalettes` is present in some other file.

```
extern const TProgmemRGBGradientPalettePtr gGradientPalettes[];
```

The compiler is not able to find this definition and so it complains at this line:

```
const uint8_t gGradientPaletteCount =
sizeof( gGradientPalettes) / sizeof( TProgmemRGBGradientPalettePtr );
```

Comment: How can I go about fixing this?  The array is defined further on in my code

Comment: Do you mean in the same file or a different one?

Comment: in the same file

Comment: Then you can replace the line `extern const TProgmemRGBGradientPalettePtr gGradientPalettes[];` with the definition of the array itself.